# Can I use ACTION_VIEW to view a JPG I've downloaded?

Tags: android

I'm having a terrible time trying to view a JPG file that I've downloaded using ACTION_VIEW in my Android App.  I can verify that the file is present and that it is the correct size.  I can pull the file from the emulator and open it on my computer, so I know the JPG is not corrupt.  I've also tried the code in [View image in ACTION_VIEW intent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1740654/view-image-in-action-view-intent).

My code is as follows:

```
// start intent to view the file  
String filename = "test.jpg"
String downloadsDirectoryPath = getFilesDir().getPath() + "/downloads";  
File file = new File(downloadsDirectoryPath + "/" + filename);

Intent i = new Intent();  
i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);  
i.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "image/*");    
startActivity(i);
```

This seems like it should be straight forward, but whenever I run the above code, I get

```
ERROR/UriImage(336): got exception decoding bitmap  
ERROR/UriImage(336): java.lang.NullPointerException
ERROR/UriImage(336):     at com.android.camera.Util.makeInputStream(Util.java:336)
ERROR/UriImage(336):     at com.android.camera.Util.makeBitmap(Util.java:307)
ERROR/UriImage(336):     at com.android.camera.Util.makeBitmap(Util.java:299)
ERROR/UriImage(336):     at com.android.camera.gallery.UriImage.fullSizeBitmap(UriImage.java:94)
ERROR/UriImage(336):     at com.android.camera.gallery.UriImage.fullSizeBitmap(UriImage.java:86)
ERROR/UriImage(336):     at com.android.camera.gallery.UriImage.thumbBitmap(UriImage.java:120)
ERROR/UriImage(336):     at com.android.camera.ImageGetter$ImageGetterRunnable.executeRequest(ImageGetter.java:173)
ERROR/UriImage(336):     at com.android.camera.ImageGetter$ImageGetterRunnable.run(ImageGetter.java:149)
ERROR/UriImage(336):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
```

Any ideas about what's going on here?

Comment: Did you add android.permission.INTERNET in your AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  Yes, I have that in the manifest.  I can actually verify that the file is there in the emulator.  I did figure out that my problem was related to permissions and not the jpg file.  See my response to the other answer for an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can make out from looking at the platform source code, you are passing in a non-existent file path in your URI.

What is the value of downloadsDirectoryPath? Bet you 15 rep points it's not fully-qualified...

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Turns out that the downloadsDirectoryPath is good, but I did figure out the problem.  Since I used FileOutputStream() instead of openFileOut(), the file was only readable by me (owner).  So, when I ditched the FileOutputStream() and used openFileOutput("test.jpg", MODE_WORLD_READABLE), it worked.  I was too focused on what was wrong with the JPG and not enough on whether ACTION_VIEW could read it.  I wanted to use subdirectories in my internal storage, but I probably can't do that.  The correct solution is probably to move external storage or make a Content Provider.

Comment: Ain't no shame in answering your own question. Post the solution in an answer and accept it. Solution worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Scott answered his own question in the comments but I'll repost as an answer since it proved helpful to me too:  Check the file permissions on the image.  I had also pulled the .jpg to verify it was fine, but the real problem was that FileOutputStream() had set the permissions by default so that ACTION_VIEW couldn't access the file.  (Personally I'd call this a bug in the viewer that it segfaults instead of logging a lack of permission to read the file, but I digress...)

As per Scott's suggestion, using openFileOutput("test.jpg", MODE_WORLD_READABLE) instead of FileOutputStream() fixes the problem.

The better solution (depending on the application) is probably to use one of these:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal