# open image from gridview using android standard viewer

Tags: android, gridview

my problem is when I want to click on an image from Gridview I want to show it by using android standard viewer 
please help me 
here is my code !

```
public class ImageAdapterForGallery extends BaseAdapter {
private Context mContext;
public static Uri uri;
static File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
        + "/Rasha Bani Hani/");
static File[] gLry = root.listFiles();
int count = gLry.length;

public ImageAdapterForGallery(Context c) {
    mContext = c;

}

public int getCount() {
    return gLry.length; }

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return gLry[position];
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    uri = Uri.fromFile(gLry[position]);

    ImageView imageView;
    imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(180, 180));

    imageView.setImageURI(uri);
    return imageView;

}}
```

need help here ! 
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can open the image intent with `ACTION_VIEW`.

Refer this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1740654/792232). On click of the image in GridView you can call the intent.

Comment: OK, my app saves images from the web , and it creates a folder , the gridview activity calls saved images from that folder so the position may of an image will change i want to pass an uri from selected image to another activity or show the selected image using standard android image viewer !

Comment: What you have tried, Can you update your question with the code you tried to show image in Image Viewer?