# How to open particular image in gallery in android

Tags: android

I am using the following code to open android gallery when an image is clicked in my app

```
  Intent intent = new Intent (Intent.AUri.parse(  "content://media/internal/images/media" ));
  intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
  mActivity.startActivity(intent);
```

how can i modify my code to open a particular image directory or a particular image

Comment: did u checked [this ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1740654/view-image-in-action-view-intent)

Comment: I did but the gallery makes toast ITEM NOT FOUND

Answer (score 0):

According to me you should try this.
In your `MainActivity` introduce a method to create intend for that
and use syntax

```
 intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.example.administrator.YOUR GALLERY APP NAME","com.example.administrator.YOUR APP.MainActivity"));
```

where `com.example.administration` is the initial name of your package